# activity not starting after i changed package name

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have changed package name after that i am getting error on last line where I tried to start activity. It was running code before refactoring.

package com.todo.aimviz;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        intent.setClassName("com.todo.aimviz", "com.todo.aimviz.Alarm");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse dramatically changes package name and sub package names in whole project. but one has to edit new package name manually in android mainfest file.